# Self-intersecting polygonal chains in a hexagon

Tags: mathematics, geometry, combinatorics

This is continuation of this [Q&A](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104586/how-many-triangles-can-you-obtain-using-the-6-vertices-and-center-of-a-regular-h). Given a regular hexagon with center at point O:

[image]

*Question:* How many self-intersecting polygonal chains are there that connect 7 points?

The [self-intersecting polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) passes through each point once
and chains should be non-isomorphic.

Comment: What is a reason of down-vote?

Comment: It does not feel much like a puzzle to me, as it mostly seems like boring case-work (especially if we have to subtract the non-intersecting ones), without much clever insight needed.

Comment: Then again, maybe I'm biased because of [this question about paths in a 3x3 square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98844/20814) which was similar and involved way too many cases to be fun to answer.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis subtracting the non-intersecting is easy.  There's only 6 of them.  It's removing the ones that cross over the midpoint without stopping that's the annoying part.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer is not correct.  It solves for undirected cycles (and I believe does so correctly) but the number for chains is different.  I will not be solving for chains.  Answer left in place in case it is somehow useful for future attempts.

> This is pretty basic math, if a bit convoluted.  There are 6 non-intersecting polygonal chains that cover all 7 points (depending on which direction you point the slice).  Anything else would intersect.

> Further, the chords that cross the center are non-legal, as they'd cause the center point to be touched more than once.

> The total number of polygonal chains if you ignore those limitations?  Simply 6!/2.  You start at A.  You have 6 options of where to go.  After that 5, after that 4, and so on.  Then you cut the result in half to acknowledge that it's not a directed graph.

> The number of graphs where a line cross over the midpoint is equivalent to the number where B and E is one point, plus where C and F are one point, plus where A and D are one point, less the number where more than one of those is true.  In this case, that means 3x5!/2 - x.  Th x is the cases where two of those are true (subtract once, because it counts once rather than twice), less the case where all three are true (which shows up 3 times in the minuend, but three times also in the subtrahend, so we need to add it back in because it's supposed to show up once).

> So, the total number of cases where it crosses the midpoint at least once without stopping is (3x5! - 3x4! + 3!)/2.  The non-intersecting is, as mentioned, 6.

> The final result is (6! - 3x5! + 3x4! - 3!)/2 - 6, which (I believe) comes to 207

Comment: There are more than 6 non-intersecting ones, for example abcdefo, bacdefo, abcdeof, bacdeof, abcdoef, bacdoef, abcdofe, bacdofe, abcodef, abcofed, abcofde, abcodfe, bacodfe, bacofde, and possibly more that I missed. "You start at A" - What about starting at O (and then A)?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ah!  You're right.  I was looking at cycles, rather than chains.  Ugh.  You're also right that the answer for chains is a lot uglier.